# How to derive scaling factors quickly for convolution theorem?

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

In case I use the following convention for Fourier transform:

$$\mathcal{F(g(t))}=G(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

and $$\mathcal{F^{-1}}(G(\omega))=g(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(\omega)e^{j\omega t}dt$$

What should be the scaling factors $a$, $b$ and $c$ for the following relations?

$$\mathcal{F}(f.g)= a \mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(g)$$

$$f*g= b\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f).\mathcal{F}(g))$$

$$f.g=c\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(g))$$

I guess $a,b,c$ should either be $2\pi$ or $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, but I'm not very sure how to directly get them by comparing with [the standard case given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

P.S: Here $j$ stands for iota.

Comment: This convention has no constant when you take the forward transform of a convolution. You can infer the others from there.

Comment: @Ian How exactly do I infer? The method is not very clear to me and it would help if you could elaborate.

Comment: The point is, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f;z)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal{F}(f;-z)$, and $\mathcal{F}(f;z)=2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f;-z)$. So once you have $\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f) \cdot \mathcal{F}(g)$, you can get the relation for the inverse FT by replacing $\mathcal{F}$ in this equation with an inverse Fourier transform. The resulting equation is expressed in terms of $-z$ instead of $z$ but that's OK since $-z$ now appears throughout.

Comment: @Ian What does $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f;z)$ and $\mathcal{F}(f;-z)$ stand for? What is the $z$ ?

Comment: It is shorthand notation for "the inverse Fourier transform of $f$ evaluated at $z$" and "the Fourier transform of $f$ evaluated at $-z$". If you like, you can think of it as $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal{F}(f) \circ m$ where $m(x)=-x$. (My $z$ is your $\omega$, sorry about that, it is force of habit).